Return component with props from composable
In a Vue project, I have a composable that provides few useful refs to components using it.
In my application, it is very likely that whichever components use the composable, it will need to render another component. Therefore, I think it would be very convenient to provide component from the composable itself, like:
export function useMyComposable() {
  const MyComponent = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('components/MyComponent.vue'));

  return { MyComponent }
}

Which works like a charm in parent:
<template>
  <my-component />
</template>

<script setup>
import { useMyComposable } from 'composables/myComposable';
const { MyComponent } = useMyComposable();
</script>

However, few of the props or v-on directives of my component shall be always fixed when using the composable. I'd like something like:
export function useMyComposable() {
  const someRef = ref(); // will be update by composable's methods

  function submit() { /* whatever */ }

  const MyComponent = defineAsyncComponent(
    () => import('components/MyComponent.vue'),
    { myProp: someRef, onSubmit: submit }, // <-- how to do this?
  );

  return { MyComponent }
}

I tried so far few paths:
// in composable
// Use Vue's "h", with MyComponent being either the component itself or a function
// This renders, but not working as expected
const MyComponent = () => h(
  defineAsyncComponent(() => import('components/MyComponent.vue'),
  { myProp: someRef, onSubmit: submit },
);

// in composable
// Tried with "withDefaults", but got errors
const MyComponent = withDefaults(
  defineAsyncComponent(() => import('components/MyComponent.vue'),
  { myProp: someRef, onSubmit: submit },
);

<template>
  <!-- in component -->
  <component :is="MyComponent()" />
</template>

Is there any way to achieve it? Possibly with both props and on methods.

It's unclear why does it belong to a composable in the first place. Is it parametrized? One of the possible implications is that useMyComposable().MyComponent  !== useMyComposable().MyComponent, this could kill some optimizations and potentially result in bugs. It looks like you need just a wrapper component

Probably not the best, feel free to propose other approaches. I wrapped in a composable because I want to automatically connect some props and methods, instead of leaving the burden to consuming component. A wrapper component could work for props, but still could be less convenient if you want to seamlessly integrate props with composable's refs. A way could be to use composable inside wrapped component too, but refs will be duplicated, thus definitely leading to errors.

" with composable's refs" - can you clarify what you mean? There are no refs in the code you posted. The solution depends on your actual case.

Edited to include props set by composable refs

This can be implemented with a composable, but this isn't a common practice. Generally components are used for view-related reusable logic, and composables are for the rest.
Unless there's a requirement to dynamically generate a component based on conditions that known in a place where a composable is called, this ca be solved with a wrapper component. A thin wrapper that passes down props and slots is easy to implement with render function, and it cannot be functional component if it needs to be stateful. It's unnecessary for a wrapper to have its own prop definitions if the props are passed as is, but correct types may be necessary for prop hints in IDE.
If a wrapper is supposed to provide a way for a parent to interact with the instance, this can be done with expose. This isn't exactly MyComponent because it differs from the original MyComponent, so it can have a different name:
// MyAnotherComponent.vue
const MyComponent = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('components/MyComponent.vue'));

export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, { slots, expose }) {
    const myProp = ref();

    function onSubmit() {}

    return () => h(MyComponent, { myProp, onSubmit, ...props }, slots);
  });
});

